# Fan and light switch wiring

Tags: wiring

I'm trying to wire 3 ceiling fans from 1 power source using push button light and fan speed.switch , Hampton bay switch push button fan and light controls.

Comment: Are you dead-set on the Hampton Bay controls? Also, do you have separate hots for the fan and light running to each fan location?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info (e.g. a diagram) before we could help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.